# Использование Proxy в классах

Tags: javascript, node.js

Решил позабавиться, сделать бесконечные range-массивы с поддержкой простейших операций.

Идея примерно следующая:
Сделать возможность создавать `URange` обьекты, которые являются "бесконечными массивами", которые можно складывать умножать и тд.

Пока получилось примерно следущее, но я пока никак не могу придумать, как перевести эту идею в ООП стиль. Потому что, пока что у меня есть лишь генерирующая обьекты функция и набор функций преобразования. А хотелось бы, чтобы можно было вызывать их как методы, пусть даже и возвращающие новые обьекты без изменения собственного состояния.

Вопрос в общем то в том, а можно ли вообще каким-то образом что-то подобное осуществить, тспользуя Proxy?

```js
function URange(start, step) {
  const uArray = new Proxy([], {
    get: ((target, p) => {
      if (p.startsWith('__')) {
        return target[p];
      }
      if (p % 1) {
        return undefined;
      }
      return start + step * p
    }),
    has: ((target, p) => p % 1 === 0)
  });

  uArray.__step = step;
  uArray.__start = start;

  return uArray;
}

function addUp(range1, range2) {
  const start = range1.__start + range2.__start;
  const step = range1.__step + range2.__step;

  const uArray = new Proxy([], {
    get: ((target, p) => start + step * p),
    has: ((target, p) => p % 1 === 0)
  });

  uArray.__step = step;
  uArray.__start = start;

  return uArray;
}

const uArr1 = URange(0, 4);
const uArr2 = URange(5, 15);

const sumUArr = addUp(uArr1, uArr2);

Array(10).fill("").forEach((_, i) => {console.log(uArr1[i], uArr2[i], sumUArr[i]);})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Интересная задачка. Немного подхаченный вариант решения, который не на 100% надежный. Но в принципе, можно как-нибудь обойти прямой вызов конструктора и пожестче.

```
class URange {
  static construct(start, step) {
    const uRange = Object.create(URange.prototype);
    return new Proxy(uRange, {
      get: ((target, p) => {
        if (Number.isNaN(+p)) {
          return target[p];
        }

        return start + step * p;
      }),
      has: ((target, p) => p % 1 === 0)
    })
  }

  constructor() {
    throw new Error('Direct constructor call are forbidden. Use "URange.construct(start, step)" instead');
  }

  add(uRange, index) {
    return this[index] + uRange[index];
  }

  subtract(uRange, index) {
    return this[index] - uRange[index];
  }

  multiply(uRange, index) {
    return this[index] * uRange[index];
  }

  divide(uRange, index) {
    return this[index] / uRange[index];
  }
}

const u1 = URange.construct(5, 5);
const u2 = URange.construct(3, 8);
const u3 = new URange();

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  console.log(u1[i], u2[i], u1.add(u2, i), u1.subtract(u2, i));
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, очень интересный вариант, в этом случае можно в принципе и из конструктора вернуть `return URange.construct(start, step)`, наверное.

Comment: А куда вы хотите вернуть результат выполнения функции конструктора?

Comment: Я имел в виду `constructor(start, step) { return URange.construct(start, step) }`

Comment: Как вы хотите сделать, я понял. Что при этом произойдет? Чему присвоится возвращенное значение? Вы хотите `this` переписать таким способом?

Comment: Это позволило бы создавать объекты через `new URange(..)`. В js же `this` игнорируется и возвращается объект записанный в `return` конструктора, если `return` конструктора возвращает объект.

Comment: Ого, никогда не обращал внимания на эту особенность. Ну тогда да, можно упростить до такого способа и вообще чистенько будет